# TensorFlow fails to build on Debian 8 - unsupported reloc 42 against global symbol

Tags: python, gcc, tensorflow, compiler-errors

I need to build TensorFlow from source as I am using it on HPC and I need the GPU support. Recently, we've migrated to Debian 8 and I am unable to build TensorFlow.

I am trying to build TensorFlow `r1.3` commit `31b316133db28cd`

My system setup:

- Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python 3.5.3
- gcc (GCC) 6.3.0
- Java 1.8.0_121
- Bazel 0.4.5
- glibc 2.19-18+deb8u10
- binutils 2.28
- cuDNN v7.0
- CUDA 8.0

`./configure` output is the following:

```
    You have bazel 0.4.5- installed.
    Please specify the location of python. [Default is /mnt/gaiagpfs/users/homedirs/mzurad/envs/tf-1.3.0/bin/python]:
    Found possible Python library paths:
      /mnt/gaiagpfs/users/homedirs/mzurad/envs/tf-1.3.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/mnt/gaiagpfs/users/homedirs/mzurad/envs/tf-1.3.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages]

    Using python library path: /mnt/gaiagpfs/users/homedirs/mzurad/envs/tf-1.3.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages
    Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MKL support? [y/N]
    No MKL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
    Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]:
    Do you wish to use jemalloc as the malloc implementation? [Y/n]
    jemalloc enabled
    Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N]
    No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
    Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N]
    No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
    Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N]
    No XLA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
    Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N]
    No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow
    Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N]
    No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
    Do you want to use clang as CUDA compiler? [y/N]
    nvcc will be used as CUDA compiler
    Please specify the CUDA SDK version you want to use, e.g. 7.0. [Leave empty to default to CUDA 8.0]:
    Please specify the location where CUDA 8.0 toolkit is installed. Refer to README.md for more details. [Default is /usr/local/cuda]:
    Please specify which gcc should be used by nvcc as the host compiler. [Default is /opt/apps/resif/data/production/v0.3-20170713/default/software/compiler/GCCcore/6.3.0/bin/gcc]:
    Please specify the cuDNN version you want to use. [Leave empty to default to cuDNN 6.0]: 7
    Please specify a list of comma-separated Cuda compute capabilities you want to build with.
    You can find the compute capability of your device at: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus.
    Please note that each additional compute capability significantly increases your build time and binary size.
    [Default is: "3.5,3.5"]: 3.5,3.7
    Do you wish to build TensorFlow with MPI support? [y/N]
    MPI support will not be enabled for TensorFlow
    Configuration finished
```

Since, we're using GCC 5 or later (6.3.0), we have to pass `--cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"` to the build command, which I did but it didn't help.

I always get the same error:
`unsupported reloc 42 against global symbol ...`
However, I am unable to trace down the issue.

```
ERROR: /mnt/gaiagpfs/users/homedirs/mzurad/tensorflow/cache/bazel/_bazel_mzurad/3806dd37ef224099fa756bede20270b4/external/protobuf/BUILD:263:1: Linking of rule '@protobuf//:js_em
bed' failed: crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc failed: error executing command
...
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /opt/apps/resif/data/production/v0.3-20170713/default/software/compiler/GCCcore/6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/crtbeginS.o: unsupported reloc 42 against global symbol _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /opt/apps/resif/data/production/v0.3-20170713/default/software/compiler/GCCcore/6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/crtbeginS.o: unsupported reloc 42 against global symbol _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: /opt/apps/resif/data/production/v0.3-20170713/default/software/compiler/GCCcore/6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/crtbeginS.o: unsupported reloc 42 against global symbol _Jv_RegisterClasses
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/_objs/js_embed/external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.o: unsupported reloc 42 against global symbol std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
/opt/apps/resif/data/production/v0.3-20170713/default/software/compiler/GCCcore/6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/crtbeginS.o(.text+0x1e): error: unsupported reloc 42
/opt/apps/resif/data/production/v0.3-20170713/default/software/compiler/GCCcore/6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/crtbeginS.o(.text+0x6b): error: unsupported reloc 42
/opt/apps/resif/data/production/v0.3-20170713/default/software/compiler/GCCcore/6.3.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.3.0/crtbeginS.o(.text+0xeb): error: unsupported reloc 42
bazel-out/host/bin/external/protobuf/_objs/js_embed/external/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/compiler/js/embed.o:embed.cc:function _GLOBAL__sub_I_main: error: unsupported reloc 42
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
```

I tried without success:

- Downgrading GCC to `4.9.2` without success.
- Trying with Python 3.6.0
- Compiling TF `r1.2` commit `4acb96a9708a7d7`
- Downgrading cuDNN to 6.0